# Как в React Native скомпилировать приложение на ios, имея комп на Windows?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

Как в React Native скомпилировать приложение на ios, имея комп на Windows?
Именно скомпилировать, а не в виртуальной машине показать.
Меня интересует, как вывести конкретный файл, что б загрузить его на плейстор эппла?  Ну по андройду вообще-то такой-же вопрос- как конечный файл получить?

Answer (score 0):

Этого нельзя сделать без виртуальной машины с macOS. Загрузка в App Store возможна только с компьютера под macOS.